# Cannot fix Geoserver Error 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: java, jetty, geoserver, http-status-code-503

I have Geoserver 2.21.1 in Windows 10 Pro 64bit.

I tweaked around to install the [vector tiles output format](https://geoserver.org/release/stable/) and enable CORS.

In GeoServer\bin I run shutdown.bat and stopService.bat and startup.bat and startService.bat as admin a couple of times

I click stop Geoserver and start Geoserver in the windows start menu

I still get

```
HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable
URI:    /geoserver/web
STATUS: 503
MESSAGE:    Service Unavailable
SERVLET:    -
Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.48.v20220622
```

When visiting `http://localhost:8585/geoserver/web` (I installed it in port 8585).

I have tried to install a Geoserver with x32 jre, but during the installation Geoserver didn't recognize it, so I used a x64 and got Geoserver installed.

How can I fix this? I am running out of solutions

Thanks

Comment: Logs would be useful.  The error is telling you that the geoserver webapp failed to deploy in the Jetty server, and the logs will tell you why.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I rin startup.bat .  I keep getting `2022-11-15 11:13:05.253:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main:
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8585` I find the task that uses the 8585 port. It is geoserver. I `taskkill` it and try to run startup.bat again, same issue. Geoserver blocks itself?

Comment: You only start GeoServer once - either from the command line, the menu or as a service.

Answer (score 1):

Not all versions are compatible with the Java JDK 8 and JRE 8. You could check if the version of Java you have supports the version of Geoserver you want to install. In the official documentation they indicate the Java versions compatible with each Geoserver.

[Java Considerations - User Manual - Geoserver](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/java.html#production-java)

In my case I was trying to run Geoserver 2.23.0 with the JDK and JRE 8 and got the 503 error. I had to uninstall the version I had of Java 8 and install version 17, and repeat the process for unzip and run the Geoserver.

`sudo apt remove openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk --purge`

`sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre`

`sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk`